# HTML: Replacement for <center>

Tags: html, xhtml

I always thought that replacing the `<center>` tag with `<div style="text-align:center;">` will get me the same results. Apparently I was wrong.

This is a portion of my HTML: 
(you can also see it in action in the page I created for this question : 
http://www.catmoviez.com/ErrorPageSO.aspx

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; background-color:red;border:5px solid black;margin-top:5px;width:750px;text-align:center;">
    <span style="width:560px;padding-right:10px;text-align:left;float:left;">
    <h1>Oops... We're sorry.</h1>

    <h3>You've just encountered an unknown error. <br /></h3>
    This site is a work-in-progress, we have already been informed of the error and will do our best to fix it. <br />
    We would be thankful if you could contact us through the appropriate button and elaborate on what caused this error to appear.<br />
    <br />
    <h3>
    You can go back to the <a style="text-decoration:underline;" href="Default.aspx">Home page</a> and continue using Moviez.NET.       
    </h3>
    </span><span style="width:180px;float:left;"><img src="Resources/Images/404.jpg" /></span>
</div>
```

I want to do 2 things:

1. Get Rid of the `<center>` tag while keeping the div in the center of the page.
2. Make sure the outer DIVs background color and border affect the inner spans.

**UPDATE:
Objective 1 is completed.
Time for objective #2.**

Comment: padding and margin will be the replacement

Comment: I solved my 2nd problem by adding float:left to the first span.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `margin: 0 auto;` on your enclosing `<div>`

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; background-color:red;border:5px solid black;margin-top:5px;width:750px;text-align:center;">
  <span style="width:560px;padding-right:10px;text-align:left;">
  <h1>Oops... We're sorry.</h1>

  <h3>You've just encountered an unknown error. <br /></h3>
  This site is a work-in-progress, we have already been informed of the error and will do our best to fix it. <br />
  We would be thankful if you could contact us through the appropriate button and elaborate on what caused this error to appear.<br />
  <br />
  <h3>
  You can go back to the <a style="text-decoration:underline;" href="Default.aspx">Home page</a> and continue using Moviez.NET.           
  </h3>
  </span><span style="width:180px;"><img src="Resources/Images/404.jpg" /></span>
</div>
```

[See it in action](http://gregory.pakosz.fr/stackoverflow/1926864.html).

Reference: [CSS: centering things](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center)

Comment: On which browsers it doesn't work? 
What about the background-color and border of the outer div? How can I apply them to my spans?

Comment: @r3zn1k Why not? It's perfectly valid HTML / CSS

Comment: @Faruz Remove `float:left` from your both your `span`, and the `div` will contain them

Comment: @K Prime Removing them causes the spans to not sit next to each other but rather act like "divs". (I've modified the example page as you suggested. See the outcome).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to simply center the text, you this css style:

```
text-align:center;
```

However, if you are looking to center the element or div itself, there are quite
some solutions for that, one being below:

```
.mydiv
{
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Or even with something like this:

```
.mydiv
{
  width:300px; // the width can sometimes be ignored based on inherent size of element.
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

Or even with something like this:

```
.mydiv
{
  margin-left:50%;
  margin-right:50%;
}
```

So you see, there can be more possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Inline content is aligned with text-align, block content is aligned with margins (set to auto for the case of centring). See [Centring Using CSS](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/).

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to center the div on the page, I usually use this method for my main wrapping div to center the page.

making the left positioning at 50% and then margining back left half of the width of the div.

example below.

```
#mainspace {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-450px;
    height:auto;
    width:900px;
    border:none;
    }
```

Comment: This method has the unpleasant side effect that given a narrow window, the element will be centred, but it will be impossible to scroll left to get to the left-most content in it.

Comment: and... FAIL . hah Thanks david, I didn't realize that, looks like i have some reformatting to do of all my sites :(

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it has worked for me when I wish I still had that

```
<center>
```

tag

```
< p style="text:align-center" >  example image or text < / p >
```