# Getting rid of <center> tag

Tags: html, html-table, center, w3c-validation

I'm trying to get rid of `<center` tag in my HTML, but apparently it is not so easy in some cases.

This answer: [HTML: Replacement for <center>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926864/html-replacement-for-center)
also did not work for me.

The following example is supposed to center both `Foo` and `Bar`, but it does not center `Bar`. What is wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<div style=" margin: 0 auto; text-align:center;">
Foo
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

If I replace `<div>` with `<center>` then everything works as indended, but `<center>` tag is deprecated...

Comment: Does the table have a fixed width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code centres the containing div but since it has `width: auto` (the default), it expands to fill the horizontal space available. This means that being centred puts it in the same position as if it was left (or right) aligned. If you want to centre that element, give it a width … but it doesn't look like that is what you want to do.

If you want to centre inline content (such as the text "Foo"), then apply `text-align` on the container.

If you want to centre block content (such as that table), then apply the auto margins you are using **to that block content** (not the container).

See also [Centring using CSS](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/)

Comment: thanks! this was the issue! after applying style to the table the `Bar` centered properly.