# Replacement for <center>

Tags: html, css, deprecated

This has been asked before by other people, but I've never seen an adequate answer. Is there a valid replacement to the `<center>` tag?

I know there's `margin: 0 auto;`, but that requires setting a width. There's also `align="center"`, but I believe that that's invalid code as well.

Is there something as simple as `<center>` that's valid? There are rare occasions where I still end up using it, even though it is deprecated. Just today, I ended up using a `<center>` to center the one button that needed centered on a web page. Yes, I could have set the width and gave it `margin: 0 auto`, but that's a lot of work for centering one single element, and it dirties up my code, which I take pride in keeping orderly. I don't really understand why `<center>` was deprecated in the first place, if nothing has replaced it.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML: Replacement for <center>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926864/html-replacement-for-center)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`text-align: center` is what you should use. In fact, the ideal way is this:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.center > div, .center > table /* insert any other block-level elements here */ {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Obviously, it's not quite as simple as you might hope for.

Personally, I just use:

```
.center {text-align: center;}
.tmid {margin: 0px auto;}
```

Then apply classes where needed.

Answer (score 12):

It's not that easy to center elements without the center-tag.

For this you need to do a workaround that works even in IE6:

You need a div wrapper around the element you want to be centered and use `text-align:center; width:100%`.
Inside this div you place another div and set `margin` to auto and `text-align:left;`

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:100%">
    <div style="margin:auto; text-align:left;">
        This Container is centered
    </div>
</div>
```

If you just want to center text you can use `<p style="text-align:center;"></p>`

This is the core. To simplify the thing, you can use a class for this (like Kolink wrote):

CSS:

```
.center {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
.center:first-child { //doesn't work in IE 6
    margin:auto;
    text-align:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="center">
    <div>
        This Container is centered
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

to center elements i use this:

```
.middlr {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
}
```

works for every/any element. works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `<center>` is deprecated is that it is not a semantic tag, rather presentational and we should steer clear of using anything in HTML that isn't semantic in nature.

It's the same reason that other presentational elements such as `<b>`, `<i>` etc have been deprecated, as there are ways of achieving the same in the CSS.

Comment: This might be useful info, but it doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Replacement for center tag:** (*You should do both*)

Use this style for parent element:

> text-align:center;

Use this style for current element:

> margin-left: auto;
>   margin-right: auto;

Answer (score 1):

```
.centered {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
}
* > .centered {
  text-align: center !important;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

this is PHP-STORM offer:
use this:

```
<div style="text-align: center;"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`text-align: center` is the equivalent CSS

Comment: Nope. Try putting a block-level element in a `<center>` and you see that the element itself is centered.

Answer (score -1):

I found this answer on a blog

```html
<img src="bullswithhorns.jpg" alt="Michael with the bull" style="width:150px;height:200px;margin:0px auto;display:block">
```

[Source](http://bloggingfear.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-center-image-using-html-5-code.html)