# How to align a form element to the center of the page?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have got a login page and I want to align form element to the center of the page.

```css
.signininp {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="signininp" type="input" name="email">
  <br>
  <input class="signininp" type="input" name="pass">
  <br>
  <input class="signininp" type="submit" name="submit" value="Giriş Yap">
</form>
```

Comment: I can't do what I want with '<center>' element.

Comment: Forget about the center element, it's obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex to align to the center of the page - simply wrap the form in a div with `display:flex and height:100vh` - and then apply `margin:auto` to your  form.

```css
.form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

form {
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <form>
    <input class="signininp" type="input" name="email"/>
    <br>
    <input class="signininp" type="input" name="pass"/>
    <br>
    <input class="signininp" type="submit" name="submit" value="Giriş Yap">
  </form>
</div>
```

You could also use `display: grid, height: 100vh and place-items:center` on teh parent element - which effectively combines `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` on the parent div.

```css
.form-wrapper {
  display: grid;  
  height: 100vh;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <form>
    <input class="signininp" type="input" name="email"/>
    <br>
    <input class="signininp" type="input" name="pass"/>
    <br>
    <input class="signininp" type="submit" name="submit" value="Giriş Yap">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
form{
    width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout to use the `<center>`tag, it resolves most of my html issues

```
 `   <center><form>
    <input class="signininp" type="input" name="email"/>
    <br>
    <input class="signininp" type="input" name="pass"/>
    <br>
    <input class="signininp" type="submit" name="submit" 
       value="Giriş Yap">
       </form></center>`
```

Comment: it's used in html 4 and it's previous versions . but not in html5 [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478067/replacement-for-center) to know about the replacement of center tag

Comment: @GiritejaBille Thanks, i dint knew it as i am new to programming , i am just 15

Answer (score -1):

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I have tried a code like this but it didn't worked for me

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

Put your form inside a div tag  and

```
 div
{
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

add this to your css file .